# NiftyNet Interpolation order

Tags: interpolation, niftynet

In NiftyNet framework - what is the purpose of `interp_order` param in config file? There is very short explanation in documentation which is not clear enough.

Why there is usually set to 0 in label section, and to 3 in image section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 means 'nearest neighbour': you only want labels to have integer values. 
3 means cubic interpolation, which is good for images that are close to continuous-valued.